# How to combine cck fields in drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have two CCK fields , 'title' & 'content'. I have to combine these two fields, so that when i press 'Add another item' button, both the above fields will add once and so on. Is this possible in drupal 6.

THANKS

Comment: The title isn't a field (it's a property of the node) so you'll most likely have to do this programmatically

Comment: @clive , thanks for your answer... its ok with the title field... just i want to combine two fields like 'book title' and 'book content'

Comment: Gotcha, [Flexifield](http://drupal.org/project/flexifield) might help, there's also a [Comparison of multifield modules](http://groups.drupal.org/node/135229), you'll probably find a solution there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , you can do that

you need to use cck 3.0 + and you can find muligroup options , just create 2 fields you need and drop them inside the multigroup , and dont forget to set your number of values to unlimited